# How to rename file with qmake INSTALLS

Tags: qmake

I want to make INSTALLS option for my project.That i want is when i call "make install"  to move and rename one or more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found real answer in Qt [forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49545-It-is-possible-to-rename-file-with-qmake?highlight=)

For example i gave my own test

```
MY_INSTALL_PATH =$$PWD/NewFolder
extra_install.path = $$MY_INSTALL_PATH
extra_install.extra = cp test.txt renamed.txt
extra_install.files = renamed.txt
INSTALLS += extra_install
```

This is create copy of test.txt named rename.txt and after that put this file in NewFolder

Comment: I don't think this answer is true any longer: with qt5, the above will *replace* the default install behavior with the `cp test.txt renamed.txt` command, but `renamed.txt` will never be installed into `NewFolder`.

Comment: This doesn't replace the default install behaviour, both things happen. I ended up with both files in the install prefix. And "mv" won't work because the extra command happens before the default cp (maybe due to make -j).

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for [QMake's INSTALLS option](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs), you can specify the action used for the install step by specifying something for ".extra"

```
configInstall.extra = cp myApp.cfg.default $$MY_INSTALL_PATH/myApp.cfg
INSTALLS += configInstall
```

If I wrote the example correctly, executing "make install" will cause `myApp.cfg.default` to be coped to the installation directory defined by `MY_INSTALL_PATH` and renamed as `myApp.cfg`.

Comment: I will up vote you because you are near, but your answer don't work for me.I will post real answer that i found in Qt forum.Thanks for attention